# How do I pass variables to PHP on sort?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am new to Jquery/Ajax - I'm trying to get the Sortable script to pass the values of some  to a PHP script.

I am trying to use this method as it has some nice UI features:
https://sortablejs.github.io/Sortable/

Docs: https://github.com/SortableJS/Sortable/blob/master/README.md#toarraystring

I've tried:

```
var serial = $('#route_list_new').sortable("toArray").val();
var serial = $('#route_list_new').val();
var serial = $("#route_list_new").sortable('serialize');
```

But i cannot seem to obtain the actual content, i think the error might be somewhere else entirely. (I AM very new to this)

HTML:

---

```
<div id="route_list_new" class="list-group col sortable-list">
  <div class="list-group-item"><p>Number 1</p></div>
  <div class="list-group-item"><p>Number 2</p></div>
  <div class="list-group-item"><p>Number 3</p></div>
</div>
```

---

SCRIPT:

---

```
route_list_new = document.getElementById('route_list_new');
new Sortable(route_list_new, {
    group: 'shared',
    animation: 250,
    onSort: function (event, ui) {
        var serial = $("#route_list_new").sortable('serialize');
        $.ajax({
            data: { serial },
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'sortable.php',
        });
    }
});
```

I would like the output variable "serial" to =

```
"Number 1, Number 2, Number 3"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply change:

```
var serial = $("#route_list_new").sortable('serialize');
```

To:

```
var serial = getSerial();
```

Then add the following function:

```
function getSerial() {
    let items = $("#route_list_new").find('.list-group-item > p'),
        serial = '';

    $.each(items, function(i, num){
        num = $(num);
        serial += num.html() + ', '
    });

    serial.slice(0,-2);

    return serial
}
```

If you do a `console.log(serial)` you will get "Number 1, Number 2, Number 3"

Answer (score 2):

You may simply use `this.toArray()`.

However, this won't give you the text values of your items, but their `data-id` attributes instead, [as per the docs](https://github.com/SortableJS/Sortable/blob/master/README.md#toarraystring).

So you should change your items from this:

```
<div class="list-group-item"><p>Number 1</p></div>
```

to this:

```
<div class="list-group-item" data-id="number1"><p>Number 1</p></div>
```

where `number1` uniquely identifies your item (doesn't have to be the same as its text).

```js
route_list_new = document.getElementById('route_list_new');
new Sortable(route_list_new, {
  group: 'shared',
  animation: 250,
  onSort: function(event, ui) {
    var sorted = this.toArray();
    console.log(sorted);
    $.ajax({
      data: {sorted},
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'sortable.php',
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sortablejs@latest/Sortable.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
<div id="route_list_new" class="list-group col sortable-list">
  <div class="list-group-item" data-id="number1"><p>Number 1</p></div>
  <div class="list-group-item" data-id="number2"><p>Number 2</p></div>
  <div class="list-group-item" data-id="number3"><p>Number 3</p></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the input Jeto. Your solution looks more clean, but i decided to go with Marcos due to a more simple coding in the remaining PHP section. - But thanks a lot for your answer.

Comment: @user3452022 No problem. However, sending text values (as opposed to unique identifiers) to your server's endpoint (PHP in your case) is bad practice, and especially sending them as a comma-separated string instead of an array. I'd suggest revisiting that whenever you can.